# Wordpress Plugin JS remove version

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Hello I want to include my js file without adding `?ver=x.x.x` to it I tried all the solutions but nothing help me to get the success

Here is my Code I am trying to add

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_script');
function register_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'customJS', plugins_url( '/assets/script.js', __FILE__ ), false);
}
```

Output it returns

```
<script src='http://localhost/wordpress/myplugin/assets/script.js?ver=5.4.4'></script>
```

Output I need

```
<script src='http://localhost/wordpress/myplugin/assets/script.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version is set by 4th param, use `NULL`, more info at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'customJS', plugins_url( '/assets/script.js', __FILE__ ), false, NULL);
```